# JQuery slider change img based on slider value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get my slider value to recognize it's value and change an image. It's a thumbs up, thumbs down concept on jquery's default functionality . So, if a user slides over to the left (thumbs down), change the img css(opacity) to show which was selected.

I thought this would suffice, but it infact removes the slider completely.

```
if ui.value >= 51{
  $('img.up').css('opacity','.8');
  alert('cool');
}
if ui.value <= 49{
    $('img.down').css('opacity','.8');
    alert('too bad');
}
```

**I made a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/VjyT7/8/). How do I get the slider values to take effect?**

I know I should probably ask/make another question as to why the sliders won't generate in multiples. But if you have any advice, I'll take that too.

Thanks for you help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add parentheses in your `if` statement.

```
$('img.up, img.down').css('opacity','.4');
if (ui.value >= 51) {
  $('img.up').css('opacity','.8');
}
if (ui.value <= 49) {
  $('img.down').css('opacity','.8');
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/psybJ/)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle. If i am not wrong this is what you wanted as final result. Try this code and check the fiddle.

```
$("#slider").slider({
 value:50,
 min: 0,
 max: 100,
 step: 50,
 slide: function( event, ui ) {
 if (ui.value >= 51){
     $('img.up').css('opacity','.8');
     $('img.down').css('opacity','.4');  
 }
 if (ui.value <= 49){
    $('img.down').css('opacity','.8');
    $('img.up').css('opacity','.4');
 }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your if statement was missing parentheses

```
$("#slider").slider({
      value:50,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      step: 50,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        if (ui.value >= 51){
          $('img.up').css('opacity','.8');
          alert('cool');
        }
        if (ui.value <= 49){
            $('img.down').css('opacity','.8');
            alert('too bad');
        }
      }
    });
```